# error on adding element to NSMutableArray in Xcode 9 Beta 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a problem with the following code (i am learning swift right now)
It happens when adding an element in line

```
items.addObjects(from: [TextField.text!])
```

The error message is :

> 2017-09-02 13:15:18.542629+0200 todolist[88230:154108272] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

I am using `XCcode 9 Beta 5`

Here is the complete part of the code

```
@IBOutlet weak var TextField: UITextField!

@IBAction func Action(_ sender: Any) {

    let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")
    var items:NSMutableArray = []
    if let tempItems = itemsObject as? NSMutableArray {
        items = tempItems
        items.addObjects(from: [TextField.text!])
    } else {
        items = [TextField.text!]
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")

    TextField.text = ""
}
```

Comment: Why `NSMutableArray`?? You cannot cast objects to mutable Foundation types. Use Swift types, that solves the problem. As you're learning Swift: Never use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains a lot of issues, this is a safe native Swift version:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    guard let textToAppend = textField.text else { return }
    var items : [String]
    if let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "items") {
       items = itemsObject
    } else {
       items = [String]()
    }
    items.append(textToAppend)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
    textField.text = ""
}
```

Please note:

- As mentioned in the comment use concrete type `[String]` rather than unrelated and unspecified `NSMutableArray`.
- With the `var` keyword you get mutability for free.
- Variable and method names start always with a lowercase letter.
- Optional values which can be `nil` – like the `text` property –  are safely unwrapped.
- The dedicated method `stringArray` of `UserDefaults` is used to avoid type casting.
- UI elements passed in `@IBAction` are always objects (`AnyObject`). Whenever possible use the actual static type (e. g. `UIButton`)